# SQL Remove duplicates keeping only records with min value from other column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to remove duplicate orders from the table, keeping only the orders that have the earliest invoice date. I came up with something like this, but this runs very slow. Keep in mind I am using MS Access 2010.

```
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM [PO Data] AS P1 WHERE [PO Number] = [PO Number] AND [Invoice Date] <> (SELECT MIN([Invoice Date]) FROM [PO Data] AS P2 WHERE P1.[PO Number] = P2.[PO Number])"
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM [PO Data] WHERE [PO Number] = [PO Number]"
```

Any ideas how to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version:

```
DELETE * FROM [PO Data] AS P1
    WHERE [PO Number] = [PO Number] AND
          [Invoice Date] <> (SELECT MIN([Invoice Date])
                             FROM [PO Data] AS P2
                             WHERE P1.[PO Number] = P2.[PO Number]
                            );
```

Has a couple strange things.  Why `[PO Number] = [PO Number]`?  Why `<>`?

Consider this query:

```
DELETE * FROM [PO Data] AS P1
    WHERE [Invoice Date] > (SELECT MIN([Invoice Date])
                            FROM [PO Data] AS P2
                            WHERE P1.[PO Number] = P2.[PO Number]
                           );
```

To speed this query, you want an index on `[PO Data]([PO Number], [Invoice Date])`.

EDIT:

If you want the earliest invoice date *overall*, just remove the correlation clause:

```
DELETE * FROM [PO Data] AS P1
    WHERE [Invoice Date] > (SELECT MIN([Invoice Date])
                            FROM [PO Data] AS P2
                           );
```

Comment: Right, this works, however it deletes only the records where `[Invoice Date]` is higher than the minimum for a given PO. It does not remove the duplicate lines with PO Numbers with the minimum date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM [PO Data] a
WHERE [Invoice Date] > (SELECT MIN([Invoice Date]) FROM [PO Data] b
WHERE b.[PO Number]=a.[PO Number]);
```

OR

```
DELETE a
FROM [PO Data] a
INNER JOIN [PO Data] b
  ON b.[PO Number]=a.[PO Number] AND a.[Invoice Date]>b.[Invoice Date]
```

The second one is faster. because of no need to execute MIN() function. It's also vary depending on your index and data size. If the number of duplicates rows is small you may apply subquery.